# Delete all Realm objects when sign out in IOS got crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I use `[realm deleteAllObjects]` to delete all `Realm` objects in local database, and then screen comeback to `Signin screen`. `Signin screen` has 2 `UITextField` for account, password input, `UIButton` for signin. App got crash when I tap `UITextField` to input account or password, and not crash when I tap `UIButton`. It's really weird that it doesn't happen all the time and crash more often when I test on `Ipod Touch 4th` than `Iphone 6, 6 plus`. Here is log for the crash:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x2544391b 0x24bdee17 0x2b3701 0x2b4d77 0x2b4d37 0xc37cb 0x29d05465 0x29d055a5 0x29cf4b51 0x29d09d1b
>   0x29aa923b 0x299baa73 0x27a52bcd 0x27a4e375 0x299d0fe7 0xd0829 0x299f6af9 0x29b45f99 0xd07bb 0x7abad5 0x299f6af9 0x29a0db73 0x7aba25 0x7ab337 0x253f5735 0x253f513f 0x253f4f1d 0x2544bc6b 0x25355083 0x25b965df 0x2a2619f5 0x2a263acb 0x299f6af9 0x29acd103 0x29a90e7d 0x2a263599 0x2a26a12d 0x2a269ccb 0x2a262d49 0x29a88fa7 0x299e5511 0x29a45d97 0x29a460b5 0x29accce9 0x29b7c187 0x29b7b75d 0x29f249eb 0x29b5f84f 0x299f0ff1 0x29f25d4f 0x299b1a57 0x299ae017 0x299eeec9 0x299ee67b 0x299bf125 0x299bd6d3 0x25405dff 0x254059ed 0x25403d5b 0x25353229 0x25353015 0x26943ac9 0x29a27189 0x16a4f9 0x24ffb873)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Comment: Please post the complete log of the crash.

Comment: @waheeda I have just add full log. Thanks!

Comment: @hyperloop I think we need to check your code. How did you create the variable realm?

Comment: seems like, in login screen, you're trying to use a Realm object that is already deleted.. Please check if objects exists before using it.